# .htaccess configuration: placement of .htaccess file and format of URLs to be rewritten

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have magento installed in /var/www/magento where /var/www is the document
root of the URL http:// localhost/ . In the default configuration I could
access my magento store with http:// localhost/magento . However, now I
have configured different websites and stores and store views under
Admin Panel -> System -> Manage Stores and would like some way of
accessing these separately in my testing environment.

For this I have checked with phpinfo() and it shows that mod_rewrite is
enabled on the system. I have tried adding the following to /var/www/magento/.htaccess
but they are not working as desired:

```
SetEnvIf Host localhost/magento/furniture
MAGE_RUN_CODE=furniture_en
SetEnvIf Host localhost/magento/furniture
MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
# ...
```

How can I get these to work. I don't need these exact URLs for accessing
the specific store components. Just don't know where to place the directives
(i.e. where to place the .htaccess file) and write them so that they make sense.

I've even tried:

```
SetEnvIf Host localhost/magentofurniture
MAGE_RUN_CODE=furniture_en
SetEnvIf Host localhost/magentofurniture
MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
# ...
```

but it does not work either, because I don't understand how mod_

Comment: How is `/magento/furniture` ever part of a hostname?

Comment: So .htaccess only rewrites based on the hostname. I've seen it rewrite others parts as well, such as changing a .php extension to .aspx in order to improve SEO. Then how gan I get _A_ setup to work, no matter which, I just want a working setup so I can navigate the the various websites and store views individually, no matter how, I'm just testing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `localhost` is a hostname, `/magento/furniture` is part of the request URI, and is not part of a hostname. Therefore, your `SetEnvIf` directives will all fail because they will never match.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to:

**System → Configuration → Web**

And turning on **Add Store Code to URLs**. This should allow you to access each store individually using their store codes in the URL. In your case, I believe it should be localhost/magento/**store_code**/.